# Using JSON to read in Game Level data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to use JSON to store data about my game to be read into my Objective-C code.

So my TwinstonesBoardModel.m file has the following methods (which are the first methods to be called when the game starts in order to set the positions of the objects on the board).  I don't know why but I split my object initializations into multiple methods for clarity.

```
    // sets the board positions for the stones
    - (void)setToInitialStateMain
    {
        // clear board so each level-load is free of previous data
        [super clearBoard];

        // set the state of two stone objects and their positions
        [super setCellState:BoardCellStateStoneOne forColumn:0 andRow:0];
        [super setCellState:BoardCellStateStoneTwo forColumn:2 andRow:3];
    }

    - (void)setToInitialStateHorizontal
    {
        [super clearBoard];

        [super setHBarCellState:HorizontalState forHBarCol:0 andHBarRow:1];
    }
```

And I have 3 extra methods for similar uses like above, just setting positions.  What I want to do is provide 100 levels worth of positions and states in a JSON file in order to be read based upon level selection.  So if I select level 54, the above functions are called and the positions and states from level 54 of the JSON file are applied.

My states are:

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BoardCellState) {
        BoardCellStateEmpty = 0,
        BoardCellStateStoneOne = 1,
        BoardCellStateStoneTwo = 2,
        BoardCellStateTarget = 3,
        HorizontalState = 4,
        HorizontalStateEmpty = 5,
        GhostHorizontalState = 6,
        VerticalState = 7,
        VerticalStateEmpty = 8,
        GhostVerticalState = 9,
        IntersectorState = 10
    };
```

And I'm dealing with positional values 0-4.

How would I go about doing this?  I'm very new to reading levels in from an external file.  I could get around hard-coding all the positions for the game, but that would take up an enormous amount of time and certainly be very inefficient.

Comment: Why not use a plist?  There is native support in Xcode and iOS for plist files.

Comment: Is there any documentation that you could reference me to that's specific to level data accessing?  Also, just based on what I have with those setter methods, does my way of thinking (use the plist to store position and state values) make sense? Can it be done?  Thanks