# Use plist to access level data (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I want to use a Plist to store data about my game to be read into my Objective-C code.

So my TwinstonesBoardModel.m file has the following methods (which are the first methods to be called when the game starts in order to set the positions of the objects on the board). I don't know why but I split my object initializations into multiple methods for clarity.

```
    // sets the board positions for the stones
    - (void)setToInitialStateMain
    {
        // clear board so each level-load is free of previous data
        [super clearBoard];

        // set the state of two stone objects and their positions
        [super setCellState:BoardCellStateStoneOne forColumn:0 andRow:0];
        [super setCellState:BoardCellStateStoneTwo forColumn:2 andRow:3];
    }

    - (void)setToInitialStateHorizontal
    {
        [super clearBoard];

        [super setHBarCellState:HorizontalState forHBarCol:0 andHBarRow:1];
    }
```

And I have 3 extra methods for similar uses like above, just setting positions. What I want to do is provide 100 levels worth of positions and states in a plist file in order to be read based upon level selection. So if I select level 54, the above functions are called and the positions and states from level 54 of the plist file are applied.

My states are:

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BoardCellState) {
        BoardCellStateEmpty = 0,
        BoardCellStateStoneOne = 1,
        BoardCellStateStoneTwo = 2,
        BoardCellStateTarget = 3,
        HorizontalState = 4,
        HorizontalStateEmpty = 5,
        GhostHorizontalState = 6,
        VerticalState = 7,
        VerticalStateEmpty = 8,
        GhostVerticalState = 9,
        IntersectorState = 10
    };
```

And I'm dealing with positional values 0-4.

How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to reading levels in from an external file. Are there any concise reference websites that you know that would help?

Comment: Do you really need to repost [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613972/using-json-to-read-in-game-level-data-in-ios)? The only difference is plist vs JSON.

Comment: And yes I do need to repost the question......there is no substantial website that I have found that can guide me around using plists